# GeoServer not mapping the hostname in schemaLocation

Tags: geoserver, wfs, configuration

I'm trying to access my WFS service from the public network but I can't establish the connection; and when checking the URL:

`https://geo.gporellana.gob.ec/geoinfo/datoslibres/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities`in the browser. I have noticed that GeoServer is not mapping the host name in the schemaLocation

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 https://192.168.1.15/geoinfo/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"`and it gives me the IP of the internal network and that is why I cannot access.

How can I get GeoServer to take the public hostname `geo.gporellana.gob.ec` to access the WFS service?

Comment: Did you set the proxy url?

Comment: just found the solution and it was to fix the base URL and with that it worked

Comment: can you add that as an answer and later accept it for others with the same problem in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found the solution and it was to fix the base URL and with that it worked

Comment: How in particular did you fix it?